# Using user variables in dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've got a scoped service, that needs to instantiate with user specific variables.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

UserService currently has a logger as it's constructor.

I'm currently doing the following through a factory, in a hacky way:

```
public class UserServiceFactory
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider _sp;
    private readonly DbContext _db;

    public UserServiceFactory(ServiceProvider sp, DbContext db) { _sp = sp; _db = db; }

    public async Task<IUserService> GetUserServiceForUserAsync(Guid userId)
    {
         var (apiKey, apiSecret) = await _db.FetchApiKeyAndSecretAsync(userId);

         var userService = _sp.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
         userService.InitUser(apiKey, apiSecret);
         return userService;
    }
}
```

I'm running into the following problems:

- I can't use `builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();` with string parameters, because as soon as it attempts to register in DI, it can't resolve the string parameters in the constructor, even though the only place I'm going to be initializing it will be in the factory, and I'll be providing said string parameters.
- If I don't use `builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();`, I'd need to use `Activator.CreateInstance<UserService>(...)`, which ties a concrete implementation to this class which is not ideal. In addition, I can't track said `UserService` for disposal when the scope gets disposed.
- It was suggested that I register a `Func<>` to return a user service. If I do this, I don't believe it will be a scoped service, and thus not be disposed of properly when the scope is destroyed.

The implementation of UserService is essentially an an HTTP Client, that will make requests with an apiKey and apiSecret of the IdentityUser. I'd like it to exist for the duration of the scope (In the case of asp.net core, the request, or in the case of being called from a Quartz job, the duration of the job), and then dispose afterwards.

UserService contains about 20 various methods, such as `FetchAccountAsync`, `BuyItemAsync(itemId, quantity)`, `SellItemAsync(itemId)`, which should make requests using the initialized httpclient. I'd like to avoid trying to initialize the apiKey/apiSecret in each method, because this will add a level of synchronization that I don't feel is needed. HttpClient is by default multithreaded, so my methods are fairly pain free:

```
Task BuyItemAsync(string itemId, int quantity)
{
    var res = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_baseUrl}/buy?itemId={itemId}&qty={quantity}");
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

How can I initialize my `UserService` with these apiKeys, apiSecrets, to be used in a scoped manner?

Comment: You'll need to register a `Func` that returns a `UserService`.

Comment: Is it possible to put the parameters in the configuration and inject a ? _`IConfiguration configuration`_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Not possible. The UserService is User specific, and relies on API Keys from the database.

Comment: Would it be an option to put IUserService into using statement? In this case all its dependencies will be cleaned by the Scoped lifecycle and the service disposed explicitly in the same method where it was created by factory.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov Nah, it's going to be used in various different places, and should be tied to the scope of the request.

Comment: Then probably the best option here is to fetch a key and a secret and set it for `IUserService` in the middleware.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov Middleware seems like the wrong approach here. I'm only going to be using this `IUserService` in a few locations. The UserFactory approach seems to be the best attempt yet, where we fetch it (Which becomes a scoped request at that point), and then I call `Init()` which will set the api key/secret. I just think it's a rather clunky workaround, as the class itself should be initialized with the strings

Comment: I checked source code I am not sure I see how `ActivatorUtility.CreateInstance` makes `IUserService` scoped. So I guess if you go with a factory you would have to wrap the code in using in order to dispose it.

Comment: @Blue The shown factory example appears to be a design issue that leads to a code smell. IMO. Reference [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)

Comment: @Blue INFO: Where does DBContext come from? Can't you instantiate it within the IUserService, or in a repository that is injected into IUserService?

Then when the UserService constructor is called you make the database call? Then this would just be standard DI with no special scenario whatsoever.

Comment: You can access `HttpContext` inside the constructor of a controller or the creation of your `UserService` with `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete I am aware of this, but in certain circumstances (ie. Fired from a quartz job), there will be no http context

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: Some of these details I've added based on your comments. Some of these may appear a little contrived because I don't know your full logic, context, or needs.

**Design**

I suggest the following

- Remove the factory.
- Go ahead and use `builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();`.
- Change the constructor of `UserService` to accept an `ISecurityContext` that will provide the API key and secret. This context will also be registered with `AddScoped`.
- Have the `UserService` use the `ISecurityContext` at runtime, and remove any properties/parameters for API key and secret (if you had them).
- Have the `SecurityService` use an `IUserProvider` at runtime, and remove any properties/parameters for user ID (if you had them).

This means no runtime data needs to be injected, no hacky method to expose, no factory, and no injecting the service provider.

At startup register the interfaces. It is important that they be scoped. They are going to share the lifetime, which will be short.

```
...
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISecurityContext, SecurityContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserProvider, UserProvider>();
```

Then implement the classes and a `Result` that can return all the contextual data.

```
public class Result
{
    public Result(string apiKey, string apiSecret, Guid userId)
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
        ApiSecret = apiSecret;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public string ApiKey { get; }
    public string ApiSecret { get; }
    public Guid UserId { get; }
}

public interface IUserProvider
{
    Guid GetUserId();
}

public class UserProvider : IUserProvider
{
    public async Task<Guid> GetUserId() => IdentityUser.GetUserId());
}

public interface ISecurityContext
{
    Task<Result> GetApiKeyAndSecretAsync();
}

public class SecurityContext : ISecurityContext
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;
    private readonly IUserProvider userProvider;

    // safe because this SecurityContext will be scoped!
    private Result _result;

    public SecurityContext(DbContext db, IUserProvider userProvider)
    {
        _db = db;
        _userProvider = userProvider;
    }

    public async Task<Result> GetApiKeyAndSecretAsync()
    {
        if (_result != null) return _result;
        
        var userId = _userProvider.GetUsedId();
        var (apiKey, apiSecret) = await _db.FetchApiKeyAndSecretAsync(userId);
        return _result = new Result(apiKey, apiSecret, userId);
    }
}

public interface IUserService
{
    Task DoWhatever();
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly ISecurityContext _context;

    public UserService(ISecurityContext context) => _context = context;

    public async Task DoWhatever()
    {
        // use the security context
        var result = await _context.GetApiKeyAndSecretAsync();

        // use the result; e.g. pass the key/secret/user ID
        // on to an HttpClient, RestClient, etc.
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Usage**

Using an `IUserService` means injecting that into your Quartz.NET job, a message handler, a web controller... wherever. In each case you may realize that one single implementation of any of these interfaces is not enough. That's OK. There are ways in dependency injection to fix that (e.g. named resolutions of multiple different concrete implementations), but I leave that to you.

Here's an example usage for a web controller.

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public MyController(IUserService userService, ...)
    { 
        _userService = userService;
        ... 
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStuff(...)
    {
        // gets the key and secret first time
        await _userService.DoWhatever();

        // uses cached versions of key, secret, guid across 
        // calls of _userService methods within scope
        var someResult = await _userService.GetSomethingElse();

        ...
    }
```

**Commentary**

This design has a few advantages

- Security details are encapsulated behind an abstraction and not mixed into the `UserService`
- The whole thing is more testable because the security details can be mocked when testing the `UserService`.
- Key and secret are cached once within the scope and can be reused across methods in `UserService` that are invoked while in the same scope.

As @NKosi said in the comments, mixing runtime data at construction time is an anti-pattern. The link they referenced, [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/), is a good read and goes into more depth.

As you add more runtime data, you can expand the properties in `Result` and logic in `SecurityContext` or you can inject more context-like objects into `UserService` returning their own result-like instances.

Comment: You're assuming in this example that fetchApiAndSecret is the same. It will vary (Pulling API credentials for each user), and there will be scopes (Quartz jobs) where IHTTPAccessor won't be possible to get user IDs.

Comment: Also, this class has about 20 various API calls. I feel like fetching this info as the top of each method is equally as stinky, if not worse. Furthermore, if I do it this, I'll need synchronization contexts for each method to initialize the httpclient with the API key and secret, instead of initializing it with the class, and not caring about synchronization at all.

Comment: That seems to reaffirm my point. All the contextual stuff (scopes, etc.) can be encapsulated outside of the `UserService`. You might need more than one implementation of `ISecurityContext`. But, I could be wrong. Perhaps more detail in your question will help.

Comment: I've updated my question with more information. I'll also read the article you linked, to see if I can get some ideas.

Comment: @Blue I updated my answer. It should solve the issue of of not having to re-obtain the data each time, but if you're doing some things with threading and more complicated scenarios this might not be enough.

Comment: `_db.FetchApiKeyAndSecretAsync();` where do I pass the user ID in, of the current logged in user (It's essentially their UserService). I need to essentially do `_db.ApiKeys.FirstOrDefaultAsync(key => key.UserId == IdentityUser.GetUserId())`

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Basically, the pattern of abstractions can be as many as you need!

Answer (score 1):

There is a placeholder pattern that I have found useful here.

**STARTUP CODE**

Define dependencies in your application startup code, something like the following. Note that .NET does not allow you to run async processing in the factory method for IUserService:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<DependencySetupMiddleware>();
services.AddSingleton(new MyDatabase());
services.AddScoped<UserServiceHolder>();
services.AddScoped<IUserService>(ctx =>
{
    return ctx.GetRequiredService<UserServiceHolder>().UserService;
});
```

The holder class just looks like this:

```cs
public class UserServiceHolder {
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }
}
```

**MIDDLEWARE CODE**

The async processing can be done in a small middleware class. For the HTTP case you would do it like this, assuming that you get the User Id after authentication. Note that dependencies cannot be added to the .NET container at runtime, but you can update the holder object:

```cs
public class DependencySetupMiddleware

  public DependencySetupMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, MyDatabase db) {

    var userId = context.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserId")
    var (apiKey, apiSecret) = await db.FetchApiKeyAndSecretAsync(userId);

    var userService = new UserService(apiKey, apiSecret)
    context.GetRequiredService<UserServiceHolder>().UserService = userService;

    await next();
  }
}
```

For Quartz you would have a similar middleware class - a `Job Factory`, which reads the job's user ID rather than using claims or the HTTP context.

**BUSINESS LOGIC**

With this code in place you can inject an IUserService into your business logic and forget about the holder class:

```cs
class MyController {

   public MyController(IUserService userService) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might already have an answer here, but let me give you a working example. Here's my assumption:

> I want to have an instance of a class that has all the things about the user available.

Here's the approach I used for [PopForums](https://github.com/POPWorldMedia/POPForums).

**Step 1:** You're using some kind of built-in ASP.NET authentication, probably cookies or something external. I won't cover that here, because there are many ways to do it, but look at `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` for more. The important part is to use a name or identifier that will be put into the token it reads back in the next step.

**Step 2:** Use middleware to get your user and make it stick. You'll start with a `ClaimsIdentity` when you use `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(schemeName)`. For [example](https://github.com/POPWorldMedia/POPForums/blob/34819945e2a7b4cc592f1b3dbfeacf469bec1e8c/src/PopForums.Mvc/Areas/Forums/Authorization/PopForumsAuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L20):

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IUserService userService)
    {
        var authResult = await context.AuthenticateAsync(schemeNameUsedFromSignIn);
        var identity = authResult?.Principal?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity != null)
        {
            var user = userService.GetUserByName(identity.Name);
            if (user != null)
            {
                // add claims to the identity if you want
                // then stash your user object in the Items collection, which lasts the duration of the request
                context.Items["TheUser"] = user;
                context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            }
        }
        await _next.Invoke(context);
```

**Step 3:** Enable getting the user anywhere you want by pulling it out of the context of the request, but isolate it to an interface so there are no hard dependencies. [Example](https://github.com/POPWorldMedia/POPForums/blob/34819945e2a7b4cc592f1b3dbfeacf469bec1e8c/src/PopForums.Mvc/Areas/Forums/Services/UserRetrievalShim.cs#L1):

```
public interface IUserRetrievalShim
{
    User GetUser();
}

public class UserRetrievalShim : IUserRetrievalShim
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserRetrievalShim(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public User GetUser()
    {
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Items["TheUser"] as User;
        return user;
    }
}
```

What I like about this approach is that any classes up and down the dependency chain can be mocked out and unit tested without all of the `HttpContext` references. `IHttpContextAccessor` does a great job isolating it, and if it's not available, you'll get a null. And in this case, you're getting *your* user object, not the one tied to ASP.NET. You can still check `HttpContext.User != null` if you want, but this similarly will be null if there's no authenticated user. I only do the above with claims because maybe other app areas may want it.

**Step 4:** In your controllers, service classes or anything in between, inject `IUserRetrievalShim` and call its `GetUser()` method to get the user.

The bottom line here is that dependency injection is *not* the place to make the user stuff contextual. DI is purely setup and configuration, not run-time context. Use your `UserService` where ever you want, and combined with this shim, you can pass its ID or whatever to those service methods. You should not expect the service to be contextual out of the box by way of injection.

With that said, your `User` objects (not to be confused with `HttpContext.User`) can be composed of whatever you want, so long as you're OK with whatever the cost is to fetch that information and hydrate the object.

Comment: OK, technically you could inject `IUserRetrievalShim` into your `UserService`, but that's a lot of mixing responsibilities in a way that I'm not sure I like. That's kind of subjective.

Comment: `UserService` is essentially a remote API. In the absolute simplest terms, I've got a job that loops through 20 users in the database, get their API keys/secrets, and for each user initializes a new `UserService`, which creates an `HttpClient` private field on construct. I do various calls on `UserService` to fetch/update information from the remote api, and then I dispose of it. Additionally, I may need to make additional calls per USER (The current mvc logged in one IdentityUser), so I may want to initialize a `UserService` there as well.

Comment: This may be a bit oversimplified, but the service I'm using, has their own framework/class, so I'd like to simply initialize it with the individual users API keys/secrets, set it as a private variable on construct, and use the various methods to interact with the remote API. I'd like to reuse this throughout the job (One scoped request), and I'd like to reuse this throughout one MVC Asp.net request (When they're browsing our website). Kit's answer seems rather convoluted to bring in `ISecurityContext`, and now an `IUserProvider`. This all seems like a big headache.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with what you're describing, the first of which is creating a bunch of `HttpClients`. Read about instancing here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0

Comment: Beyond that, you're mixing a lot of concerns which makes it harder to debug and test things. Don't create more than you have to, especially in this case with `HttpClients` because you could run out of outbound ports. If you need to carry something throughout a request, see what I did with `HttpContext.Items` and the stuff I wrapped around it. But again, avoid creating things you don't need. Memory is cheap, but it's not unlimited. :)

Comment: I get that with the ports, but unfortunately I'm limited to using the vendors APIs. It's not something I can simply move away from. I will be disposing of the instances when I'm done with them.

Comment: I don't think the vendor API is what's impeding your design choices. If you follow the guidance in the linked doc, you can avoid the problem with the clients.